# Question about “criticism” and “critique”

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Are *criticism* and *critique* mass nouns?

If not, what semantic area does their countable usage refer to?

Comment: What does the dictionary say?

Answer (score 1):

OED lists both countable and mass senses for both, but the examples given for “critique” as mass seem to me ambiguous on that point, and my own sense of that word is that it strongly tends to be countable.

Comment: It would help if you could give examples of those senses for us.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, whilst I was in architectural school, criticism was abundant, never-ending, and hailed from every direction. The word critique was reserved for the formal event where criticism was delivered by invited judges. Critique was not only not mass, it was singular. I agree with Brian that my sense is that *critique* is a countable noun, while *criticism* can be either countable or mass. As for semantic area, in my example, critique is idiomatic. Architects love to wallow in words with meanings exclusive to their cult.